Change just the descriptions of inherited model fields
I have two pydantic models- one that has fields and one that inherits those fields. I want the inherited fields to be exactly the same, but I’d like to change their descriptions.
class Model(BaseModel):
   a: int = Field(description=“a value from the parent”, default=2)


class ChildModel(Model):
   b: int = Field(…)
   
   # a is a field here too with the same defaults, but with the description “a value from the child”

Is there a way to do this without redefining the entire field? I’ve seen that the ConfigDict might have something that could do this?

i never go to this level of complexity, so it will be interesting to see an answer...
